View From the Foot of a Mountain Diskworld
I'm putting together a world for a story that is a disk world composed of a single enormous mountain that peaks at the center. About half of it is covered in water, leaving the exposed part at about the size of the pacific ocean. The closer to the peak you get, the steeper the mountain is resulting in a peak that is a hundred kilometers higher than the sea level.
My question is: would the mountain peak be visible from everywhere else on the continent, and about how prominent would it be? Would the view significantly differ at the foot of the mountain as opposed to about halfway up?
My gut instinct is that far from the peak, at the foot of the mountain, although it would be visible, it wouldn't dominate the sky.

What's the atmosphere like?  Is it like Earth's atmosphere with declining density with increased altitude, or does the magic of the disk world keep it to 1 atm or similar at all altitudes?  As per similar questions, on a clear day on Earth we can see the moon which is hundreds of thousands of km away, but we're only looking through a very thin layer of atmosphere - what's the situation on your world?

(a) What is the diameter of the disk? (b) What's the diameter of the base of the mountain? (If A and B are the same, what's holding in the water?) (c) What is the peak height of the mountain? (d) Stack Exchange allows one and only one question per post (VTC:Needs More Focus). (e) What research have you done? I recommend starting with long distance line-of-sight records.

In order for "half" of it (do you mean half the area or half the radius?) to be about the size of the Pacific ocean, the radius of the disk would be in the thousands of kilometers. A hundred kilometer high peak would mean an average slope small enough that while people would be technically aware of its existence, most of the time they would not really consider it, thinking of the land as being level.  There would be no "mountain" in their view until it is brought to their attention that "level" is slightly below the obvious horizon.

For anything resembling a landscape instead of a perfect geometrical object, there will be places where you can't see one part from another part, no matter the relative dimensions of the parts.
You can find who can see what from where and how much angular space it would take up in their field of view by sketching your diskworld and using a straight edge and protractor to check line of sight and the angle from the horizon line to the sight line.


When you're thousands of km away, even a 100km tall mountain only rises a couple degrees above the horizon. Being at the base of even a slight hill could block your view.

Thank you! This helped me understand the situation a lot.

Looking through Atmosphere
Near the rim, the line of sight to the peak might pass through hundreds of miles of atmosphere. Even slight amounts of haze or dust or turbulence in the atmosphere might add up to blocking LOS. This could affect the lower and middle altitudes, leaving the top visible, or it could affect even the top.
Refraction
Even if light passes, the waves might be altered by atmospheric refraction. This might allow visibility where no geometric line of sight exists.
